# mysql query update with php

Tags: php, mysql

please help me understand why this update query wont update my database record? i know theres a bunch of similar questions and i've read them as well but still i didnt know whats wrong...

this is how i input:

```
<form class="mx-3 my-3" role="form" method="post" action="buka_akun.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputUserName" class="font-weight-bold">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputUserName" id="inputUserName" aria-describedby="InputUserNameHelp" placeholder="Masukkan username Anda...">
        </div>          
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary border-0 mr-2" name="buttonBukaAkun" style="background-color: rgba(18, 137, 167,1.0);">Buka Absen</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary border-0 mr-2" name="buttonTutupAkun" style="background-color: rgba(18, 137, 167,1.0);">Tutup Absen</button>
</form>
```

my php:

```
<?php
    include("header.php");
    include("db_connect.php");

    $flag = 0;

    if(isset($_POST['buttonBukaAkun'])){
        $username = $_POST['inputUserName'];

        $query_buka_akun = "UPDATE 'user_login' SET 'activate' = '1' WHERE 'username' = '$username'";

        $result_buka_akun = mysqli_query($connection, $query_buka_akun);

        if($result_buka_akun){
            $flag = 1;
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['buttonTutupAkun'])){
        $username = $_POST['inputUserName'];

        $query_tutup_akun = "UPDATE 'user_login' SET 'activate' = '0' WHERE 'username' = '$username'";

        $result_tutup_akun = mysqli_query($connection, $query_tutup_akun);

        if($result_tutup_akun){
            $flag = 1;
        }
    }
?>
```

database table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_login(
id_login int(255) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
username varchar(255),
password varchar(255),
level varchar(255),
activate int(2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Submit, replace the `<button>` tag with `<input type='submit'>`.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary border-0 mr-2" name="buttonBukaAkun" style="background-color: rgba(18, 137, 167,1.0);" value="Buka Absen" />
```

And, do not put the table column name between quotes.

```
$query_buka_akun = "UPDATE user_login SET activate = '1' WHERE username = '$username'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should firstly escape your POST Data.

Why using ' in your Statement?

```
"UPDATE 'user_login' SET 'activate' = '1' WHERE 'username' = '$username'";
```

should look like

```
'UPDATE `user_login` SET `activate` = '1' WHERE `username` = '.$username;
```